# Shell Script thinks directory does not exist when running cd

Tags: bash, cd

I have a shell script (which I source into .bashrc) that allows me to jump to my projects directory from anywhere.

```
cdp(){
  proj="~/dev/projects/$@/"
  builtin cd $proj
}

_my_cdp()
{
  local cur opts
      cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      opts=$(ls ~/dev/projects/)
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
}

complete -o nospace -F _my_cdp cdp
```

The problem is, the `cd` on line 3 says:

```
bash: cd: ~/dev/projects/jsonparse/: No such file or directory
```

Here is the full console output showing the error and proving the directory exists.

```
amflare:~$ cd dev/projects/ (go to dir)
amflare:~/dev/projects$ ls -al (look at contents)
total 68
drwxrwxr-x 17 www-data amflare 4096 Dec 29 13:11 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 amflare amflare 4096 Dec  6 17:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data amflare 4096 Dec 22 17:33 bot
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data amflare 4096 Dec 20 15:17 jsonparse
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data amflare 4096 Dec 28 19:58 magic
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data amflare 4096 Nov 11 14:42 test
amflare:~/dev/projects$ cd (go to home)
amflare:~$ cdp (run autocomplete)
bot         jsonparse   magic       test
amflare:~$ cdp jsonparse (pick target)
bash: cd: ~/dev/projects/jsonparse/: No such file or directory
amflare:~$ (still in home)
```

I've tried everything I can think of and a few things google gave back for other distros (I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04). No matter what I do, the shell script will not acknowledge the existence of anything inside `~/dev/projects/`. Additionally, it does not work when I have the functions in `.bashrc` itself, so I don't think it is a subshell problem. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

Comment: That's because the tilde isn't expanded. Use `proj=~/"dev/projects/$@/"` with the tilde out of the quotes. Or use the variable `HOME`: `proj="$HOME/dev/projects/$@"`. Note, though, that using `$@` is not really good. What do you want if there are several arguments?

Comment: Consider running this code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- there's *lots* wrong with it; that may not catch everything, but it's a place to start.

Comment: ...see, f/e, [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `ls` is an inappropriate tool for programmatic use. And the lack of quoting throughout leads to its own issues.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I had run it through there, but I guess I did something wrong since doing it again showed issues. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the tilde isn't expanded. Use `proj=~/"dev/projects/$@/"` with the tilde out of the quotes. Or use the variable `HOME`: `proj="$HOME/dev/projects/$@"`. Note, though, that using `$@` is not really good. What do you want if there are several arguments?

---

Also, don't use `opts=$(ls ~/dev/projects/)`. Use `compgen` directly like so:

```
cdp() {
  local proj=~/dev/projects/
  builtin cd "$proj$1"
}

_my_cdp() {
    local proj=~/dev/projects/
    local i p
    COMPREPLY=()
    while IFS= read -r i; do
        printf -v p '%q' "${i#"$proj"}"
        COMPREPLY+=( "$p" )
    done < <(compgen -d -- "$proj$2")
}
```

When completing, the completion function `_my_cdp` will have as parameter `$2` the word being completed; we give that to `compgen -d` (with the prefix `$proj`), and loop through the results (the results are output one per line—so yeah, it'll break if you have newlines in your directories). With each name found, we quote it using `printf '%q'`, while using a parameter expansion to remove the prefix `$proj`. The quoting is used so as not to break if directory name contains spaces or funny characters (e.g., glob characters), and we populate the array `COMPREPLY` one term at a time. That's a rather robust way to deal with completion (yet not 100% unbreakable, but it'll do the job for your non-crazy directory names!).

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks. As for $@, I based this off of someone else's code and didn't bother to change it. I have now though.

Comment: @tbirrell: answer edited slightly to have better completion!

Comment: Ah. Cheers! I was actually in the middle of trying to figure that out. There are many moving parts here I don't understand. Would it be too much trouble to get run down, code golf style?

Comment: @tbirrell: added a paragraph; not sure whether it all makes sense! if you have any specific question, feel free to ask for some clarification.